# Magento 2.1.2 placeholder image for product details page

Tags: product-images, magento-2.1.2, placeholder

I am running into the issue of product details page with the default placeholder image.

I have changed the placeholder in the 4 sections available under:
Stores > Configuration > Catalog > Catalog > Placeholder images.

I have flushed the cache, removed static files, redeployed static content. Nothing. My custom placeholder image is applied everywhere throughout the site, except on the product details page.

Am I missing something? This should be part of the settings I have already changed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a core issue. You can read about it, and also fix it from the official Magento2 GitHub:

MAGETWO-53036: [GITHUB] Base image placeholder issue #4549 (https://github.com/magento/magento2/commit/b065cd3e7201c1f7b0b45efe29020662d15ad9f1)