# Magento 2.1.7 no option to change placeholder image in product page

Tags: magento2, admin, image, placeholder

I've found that I've got no option in admin as stated in this post
ref: https://www.alexcorradi.org/blog/2016/11/14/how-to-change-product-image-placeholders-in-magento-2

Mine looks like this:
[image]

Is this a bug? does any one have more info on this please?
Thanks.

Comment: Similar yes! **Missing Product Page Featured Image** on Mine.

Comment: the article seems approx one year older, in this one year there are a lot of changes done in Magento 2, the option you are looking for may be removed

Comment: Then we are expected to just copy and image to cutom theme in **Magento_Catalog/images/product/placeholder/image.jpg** not they way forward I wonder why remove such feature?

Comment: @Piyush as you can see is obvious that if an image isn't provided for a product the default image in product page is used which is the Magento logo, as you already mentioned the ability to change the default image in product page from admin has been removed. so that;s what I wanted to do, I know I have a few options but not sure which one is the best approche.

Comment: the four options visible in you screenshot are for the product placeholder image only, you can upload your image there and it will work, the removed option was for featured image

Comment: it was a core bug and fixed in Version 2.2 [Check here](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/4549)

Comment: @Piyush I have uploaded all four of them as you can see in the screen shoot  it only  appears in the product listing in categories but not in product page.

Comment: This might explain why https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/146132/magento-2-1-2-placeholder-image-for-product-details-page     ref: https://github.com/magento/magento2/commit/b065cd3e7201c1f7b0b45efe29020662d15ad9f1